# What is the entropy and/or equation of state of a partition function such as $Z=\int D\phi \exp (i S[\phi]/\hbar)$?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, path-integral, partition-function, wick-rotation

At this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(mathematics), it is claimed that the following partition function:

$$
Z=\int D\phi \exp (-\beta H[\phi]) \tag{1}
$$

is a consequence of taking the usual partition function of statistical physics $Z=\sum \exp (-\beta H)$ but for an uncountable amount of random variables.

Later in the article, it is claimed that all partition functions have an entropy given by:

$$
S=k_B ( \beta\langle H \rangle +\log Z[\beta])
$$

My questions are :

1. Does $S$ also holds for a functional integral of type (1)?
2. A functional $H[\phi]$, assuming locality, is often written as $H[\phi]=\int_{t_0}^{t_1}\int_{z_0}^{z_1}\int_{y_0}^{y_1}\int_{x_0}^{x_1}\phi[t,x,y,z]dxdydzdt$. How does the term $\langle H \rangle$ connect to $\phi[t,x,y,z]$? For instance, in usual statistical physics, a partition function such as

$$
Z[\beta,p]=\sum_q \exp (-\beta (E[q] + p V[q]))
$$

will have this entropy: $S=k_B(\beta \langle E \rangle +\beta p \langle V \rangle + \log Z[\beta,p]$. Here we can see that the entropy is a sum over the averages the exponentiated terms.

In the case of $H[\phi]$ becoming $\langle H \rangle$, are any structure present in $\phi[x,y,z,t]$ or $H[\phi]$ preserved to $\langle H \rangle$. For example if $\phi[x,y,z,t]=R\sqrt{-g}$ (the Einstein Hilbert action) can we connect $\langle H \rangle$ to $g$?

3. How does adding the imaginary term:

$$
Z=\int D\phi \exp (i S[\phi]/\hbar)
$$

change the entropy relation above?

---

edit: At the very least, I am assuming that at some point along with the derivation of $S$ from (1), one will encounter a structure:

$$
\langle H \rangle= \int D\phi H[\phi]\exp(-\beta H[\phi]) \tag{2}
$$

?

---

edit2: Am correct to assume that if

$$
\Phi[b]-\Phi[a]=\int_a^b \phi[\tau]d\tau
$$

then from (2) it follows that:

$$
\begin{align}
\langle H \rangle&=\int D\phi (\Phi[b]-\Phi[a])\exp(-\beta (\Phi[b]-\Phi[a])\\
&=\langle (\Phi[b]-\Phi[a]) \rangle
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I would suggest separating your 3rd question off into a separate question. It is really a different question from your first 2